# Yii2 problem with custom URL with opional param

Tags: url, yii2

Working with Yii2, advanced project template, I defined this URL rule (among others) in my config/main.php file:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        **[
            'pattern'   => 'past-events/<page:\d+>',
            'route'     => 'event/past',
            'defaults'  => [
                'page'  => 1
            ]
        ]**
    ],
],
```

It should create/understand URLs like these:

/past-events
/past-events/2
...

But when I use this code:

`Url::toRoute(['event/past']))`

It returns "/event/past" and that URL doesn't work if I click on the generated link (404, not found).

What am I missing, please?

Comment: Have you tried changing 'enableStrictParsing' to false? https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#named-parameters